# I can't open youtupe att all on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have the latest version of Google Chrome, I can open all other websites beside YouTube.

I'm getting this message: "This web page is not available".

What is strange I can open YouTube with Firefox.
Can you help me please? I'm stuck with this problem since one week and I have tried everything but no solution.

Comment: Clear your DNS cache in chrome : http://www.redsome.com/flush-clear-dns-cache-google-chrome-browser/ and reset your chrome to factory settings without any addon : https://malwaretips.com/blogs/reset-chrome-settings/

Comment: If you go to: chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings you can factory reset your browser

Comment: I'already did but no progress

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting your cache and browsing history.

Menu -> Settings -> Content settings and Clear browsing data under **Privacy**

Also, if you scroll down even more and open the advanced options, there is an option to reset everything back. Not sure why that would work but it is an option. Just remember to backup your stuff or link to your Google account.

Comment: thanks @FunkHaus for you answer , I've already tried that but without any  success